# declare "data source" in a connection string as 'variable' in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, variables, connection, runtime, datasource

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim bs As New BindingSource

    m_DataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID", "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Users\rebel23\Desktop\sampledata.mdb")

    m_DataAdapter.Fill(m_DataSet)

    bs.DataSource = m_DataSet.Tables(0)
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs
    txtAnimal.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "TextBox6.text")
    txtSpecies.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "TextBox7.text")
```

In the above code i want to change the "data source" and declare it as TextBox1.text
So that the user will decide the data source at run time... 
Also i want the same for 'Table1' and 'ID'
but how to do that??

Comment: Did you try not putting "" around the textbox name in the binding?

Comment: the error is right now in "data source"... first let me correct that and then the other parts will be compiled for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim myTableName As String
    Dim myOrderingColumn As String
    Dim mybind1 As String
    Dim mybind2 As String

    myTableName = TextBox3.Text
    myOrderingColumn = TextBox4.Text
    mybind1 = TextBox6.Text
    mybind2 = TextBox7.Text

    m_DataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & myTableName & " ORDER BY " & myOrderingColumn, "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & TextBox5.Text)

    m_DataAdapter.Fill(m_DataSet)

    bs.DataSource = m_DataSet.Tables(0)
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs
    txtAnimal.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "" & TextBox6.Text & "")
    txtSpecies.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "" & TextBox7.Text & "")


End Sub
```

hey i got the code man !!!! its working .... thanks a lot for your support and suggestions @matzone

Answer (score 0):

I did it in different way ..

```
Dim myConn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection( "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\rebel23\Desktop\sampledata.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypass")

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand 
Dim ds as DataSet = New DataSet

myConn.Open() '--> open conn
cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID", myConn)

cmd.Fill(ds, "predator") ' ---> named dataset as Predator

txtAnimal.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables("predator"), "'" & TextBox6.text & "'")
txtSpecies.DataBindings.Add("Text",ds.Tables("predator"), "'" & TextBox7.text & "'")

' ....
' .....

cmd.Dispose()
ds.Dispose()
cnn.Close()
```

Comment: my questions are still unanswered !!!!

what about "data source" ???????

@matzone

Comment: tried `myTableName = TextBox3.Text
        myOrderingColumn = TextBox4.Text
m_DataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & myTableName & " ORDER BY " & myOrderingColumn, "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; DataSource=" & TextBox5.Text)`

and everything as you told but still getting an error (run time)

error details- 

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Message=Could not find installable ISAM.
  Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine

@matzone

Comment: My first requirement is that the user should be able to declare the data source.... in your code whre is the user telling the data source.. its already defined in the code...

the topic is -declare “data source” in a connection string as 'variable' in VB.NET

Comment: declaring data source at run time

Comment: @ʞuɐɹdRebel: in the first line .. there's declaring connection with the datasource ! .. so, what do you want ? .. what kinda text in textbox6 an 7 ?